# Zoom API - Request to check email does not work

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, zoom-sdk

I am trying to consume Zoom's API using PHP and Oauth2. I was able to connect to the aplication and get the token using the generic lib [oauth2-client](https://oauth2-client.thephpleague.com/). But, when I try to make a simple request, I get an error, saying that the email is missing. This is my code:

```
<?php  

session_start();

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$provider = new \League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\GenericProvider([
    'clientId'                => 'meuclientid',
    'clientSecret'            => 'meuclientsecret',
    'redirectUri'             => 'http://localhost/teste_oauth2/',
    'urlAuthorize'            => 'https://zoom.us/oauth/authorize',
    'urlAccessToken'          => 'https://zoom.us/oauth/token',
    'urlResourceOwnerDetails' => 'https://api.zoom.us/v2/users/me'
]);


// If we don't have an authorization code then get one
if (!isset($_GET['code'])) {    
    $authorizationUrl = $provider->getAuthorizationUrl();

    // Get the state generated for you and store it to the session.
    $_SESSION['oauth2state'] = $provider->getState();

    // Redirect the user to the authorization URL.
    header('Location: ' . $authorizationUrl);
    exit;

// Check given state against previously stored one to mitigate CSRF attack
} 
elseif (empty($_GET['state']) || ($_GET['state'] !== $_SESSION['oauth2state'])) {

    unset($_SESSION['oauth2state']);
    exit('Invalid state');

} else {

    try {

        // Try to get an access token using the authorization code grant.
        $accessToken = $provider->getAccessToken('authorization_code', [
            'code' => $_GET['code']
        ]);

        $request = $provider->getAuthenticatedRequest(
            'GET',
            'https://api.zoom.us/v2/users/email',
            $accessToken,
            ['email' => 'meuemail@gmail.com']
        );


        var_dump($provider->getResponse($request));
        die('aqui');

    } catch (\League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Exception\IdentityProviderException $e) {

        // Failed to get the access token or user details.
        echo $e->getMessage();
        exit;

    }
}

?>
```

As you can see, I am passing the email on the request. But I am getting the Fatal error: Uncaught GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException: Client error: GET https://api.zoom.us/v2/users/email resulted in a 400 Bad Request response: {"code":300,"message":"Email is required."}

Can anyone help me?

Comment: This is a `GET` request. The 4th parameter is `$options`. I guess you need to change with `'https://api.zoom.us/v2/users/email?email=meuemail@gmail.com',` and remove the 4th parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using

```
['email' => 'meuemail@gmail.com']
```

which is not allowed in the function **$provider->getAuthenticatedRequest**

You need to pass it with the existing URL:

```
        $request = $provider->getAuthenticatedRequest(
            'GET',
            'https://api.zoom.us/v2/users/email?email=meuemail@gmail.com',
            $accessToken
        );
```

I hope this helps..!!

Zoom API Reference: https://marketplace.zoom.us/docs/api-reference/zoom-api/users/useremail

OAuth Reference: https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-client